# babel-node installation "Only RSA and DSA public keys are allowed"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs, babel-node

I'm having trouble installing `babel-node`

`npm i -g babel-node`

```
> babel-node@6.5.2 postinstall /Users/.../.../node_modules/babel-node
> node message.js; sleep 10; exit 1;

/Users/.../.../node_modules/ssh-key-to-pem/index.js:210
    throw new Error('Only RSA and DSA public keys are allowed');
    ^

Error: Only RSA and DSA public keys are allowed
```

Comment: FYI This package is almost certainly malicious and is typo-squatting babel-cli in order to exfiltrate people's SSH keys, you were saved by the fact that you use non RSA/DSA keys. I've reported it to NPM in the hopes that they remove it.

Answer (score 14):

I solved this...it's not intuitive. I'll leave this up in case someone else runs into this issue.

`npm install --save-dev babel-cli`

https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/

Comment: I'd like to point out that the full answer is: The command `babel-node` is *not* provided by the package `babel-node` (which is a [mock package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-node/v/6.5.2)) but rather by the package `babel-cli` and *that's* why installing it solves the issue. Plus, if you already saved `babel-node` to your `package.json`, remove it.